# Most effective index for BIGINT column which is only ever filtered/queried by positive/negative sign?

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

I inherited a very large and active PostgreSQL table with a `BIGINT` column containing scalar measurements for samples like so:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sample (
    id       SERIAL    PRIMARY KEY,
    name     TEXT      NOT NULL,

    ...
);

CREATE TABLE measurement (
    id       SERIAL    PRIMARY KEY,
    sampleid INTEGER   NOT NULL,
    value    BIGINT    NOT NULL,
    created  TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),

    ...

    FOREIGN KEY (sampleid) REFERENCES sample (id)
);

CREATE INDEX ix_measurement_created ON measurement (created);
```

Users query samples first based on whether `measurement.value` is greater than zero and then on additional criteria.  These queries were originally painfully slow.

Adding `CREATE INDEX ix_measurement_value ON measurement (value);` improved performance almost tenfold.

I should have been happy with this result but I can't help but feel that this is not the most efficient solution.  In practice the *actual values* stored in the column are irrelevant as 99% of requests are:

- ...*always* scoped first for `value > 0` or `value <= 0`.
- ...*never* looking for values within specific ranges.
- ...*never* looking for specific values.

Would either of the following be more effective?

- A *single* [index expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/indexes-expressional.html) for:

  - `CREATE INDEX ix_measurement_pos ON measurement (value > 0);`
- *Separate* index expressions for

  - `CREATE INDEX ix_measurement_pos ON measurement (value > 0);`
  - `CREATE INDEX ix_measurement_neg ON measurement (value <= 0);`

I'm not sure how to simulate the production environment's stats/load well enough to evaluate the approaches on my own (advice on that would be appreciated as well!).

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that the queries are being generated/issued by an ORM which I have no control over - the above `sample` / `measurement` join is just one part of a very large and terrible thing.

**Edit #2:** This is a PostgreSQL 9.3 database that cannot be upgraded beyond 9.4, per vendor requirements.

**Edit #3:** A [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/indexes-partial.html) was suggested, but because the queries are ORM generated it's difficult to determine which columns a partial-index should contain ...unless someone has advice on that!

Comment: You probably want a partial index `create index on measurement (..) where value > 0`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - are you suggesting a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/indexes-partial.html)? If so, could you explain why that's preferable to an [index expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/indexes-expressional.html)?  For a partial index I'm not sure which columns I should be included in `(..)`.

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (sampleid) REFERENCES sample (id)` You'll need a supporting index here, or your cascades will invoke seq scans.

Comment: The most likely explanation for a ten-fold increase when you are only querying by sign is that whichever value is most commonly queried for (say, >0) is a small percentage of the results in the table. There is no speedup from an index when there are two values of interest and about the same number of each.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a specific query whose performance you're concerned about, it is difficult to address:

> Would [these specific indexes] be more effective? […] I'm not sure how to simulate the production environment's stats/load well enough to evaluate the approaches on my own (advice on that would be appreciated as well!).

This seems to be the crux of the issue.

To evaluate what will help specific queries, you want to get the execution plan by [using `EXPLAIN` on *that specific query*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html).

If you're trying to understand the inner workings of:

```sql
SELECT count(sampleid)
FROM measure
WHERE value > 0
;
```

you use the `EXPLAIN` statement, specifying what behaviours should be in the output. For example:

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, COSTS)
SELECT count(sampleid)
FROM measure
WHERE value > 0
;
```

With the output from that (maybe use other options for the output, if you're concerned about other aspects of performance), you can then seek to make an index addressing some specific part of the execution of the query.

Then, to verify whether your index has improved what you want, you need some test runner that will hammer the server with queries, before and after your proposed change. That will give you a [performance benchmark](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42012/how-can-i-benchmark-a-postgresql-query) for comparing before and after the change.